# 3D PC game where you could build a vehicle to collect containers (and parts) that would allow you to access more difficult areas

Tags: story-identification, video-games

About 2010 (maybe earlier) I played a 3D PC game where you needed to navigate around a series of interconnected indoor areas with a range of platforms (at a wide variety of heights), long spindly connecting bridges, ramps of varying heights, force-fields (some of which had holes in them), floor death grids, fixed and moving lasers, etc, in order to collect (numbered?) containers. The arenas were fairly bland, consisting of a [series of interconnected shapes](https://youtu.be/hTehcvSgyWI?t=1164) with flat colours, colour-coded to indicate that you'd moved into a new area.

The key mechanic of the game was that you started with a very simple land-based vehicle comprised of two wheels (mapped forward and backward to four keys) and a simple axle between them, but that you could collect additional parts for your machine such as turning circles, larger or more powerful wheels, multiple axles, springpads, boosters, etc) and map them to different keys, allowing you to build larger, faster and more manoeuvrable machines that could execute tight turns, move at speed and jump, which meant that you could now gain access to areas that were previously inaccessible.

I particularly recall that one of the parts (some sort of booster) was nerfed in an updated version because people (including myself!) had basically been making vehicles that could access top-level containers by simply boosting up to them, bypassing hazards and tricky jumps entirely.

Comment: Possibly a Unity game? Or made in the Unity engine. I'm really not sure about that, so leaving it in a comment.

Comment: Something like GearBlocks? Seems that you may also create a custom game on its basis.

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi - No. Much *much* less complex. Your vehicle had (I think) only a few potential linkage points.